# How to set writer in PDFStamper?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfstamper

I want to update the writer in PDFStamper in itext. I am using getWriter method to get the writer of my stamper object. Updated the run direction for that writer but I'm not able to understand how can I set this writer to stamper. Adding the code I tried here:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.getWriter().setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
System.out.println(stamper.getWriter().getRunDirection());
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

This is not working and somehow run direction stays the same. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You cannot _set_ the writer of a `PdfStamper`. Also, have you read the JavaDocs of the methods involved? The `setRunDirection` JavaDocs say "This is only used as a placeholder as it does not affect anything."

Comment: Is there anyway to set run direction in stamper?

Comment: Run direction can be set while writing content. Here you are not writing anything, only simply reading it

Comment: If I remember correctly, the run direction in iText before version 7.x only could be non-LTR inside tables (see `PdfPTable`) or when using `ColumnText` directly. (I never needed to create non-LTR content, so please take this with a grain of salt.)